# How to install managed package using Salesforce DX CLI?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, github, ci, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am trying to follow the [Trailhead module on CI](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/sfdx_travis_ci/units/sfdx_travis_ci_wire_it) and [Salesforce DX](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/sfdx_app_dev/units/sfdx_app_dev_setup_dx). I tried to push some of my Lightning components which depend on a managed package in App Exchange. I would like to know how to install a managed package using Salsforce DX CLI so that i can use that command in my `travis.YML` file for my CI integration.

Here is the script for my Travis file

```
sudo: true
dist: trusty
cache: false
env:
- URL=https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx-linux-
amd64.tar.xz
before_install:

- export SFDX_AUTOUPDATE_DISABLE=true
- export SFDX_USE_GENERIC_UNIX_KEYCHAIN=true
- export SFDX_DOMAIN_RETRY=300
- wget -qO- $URL | tar xJf -
- "./sfdx/install"
- export PATH=./sfdx/$(pwd):$PATH
- sfdx update
- sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid $CONSUMERKEY --jwtkeyfile 
assets/server.key
--username $USERNAME --setdefaultdevhubusername -a DevHub
script:
- sfdx force:org:create -f config/project-scratch-def.json -s -a 
PackageInstallation
- sfdx force:org:list
- sfdx force:org:display
- sfdx force:user:password:generate -u PackageInstallation
- sfdx force:org:display
- sfdx force:org:open -u PackageInstallation
- sfdx force:source:push -u PackageInstallation
- sfdx force:apex:test:run -u PackageInstallation -c -r human
```

I get the following error as my components depend on the app exchange components:

> No COMPONENT named markup://ldt:datatableDev found :

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This helped me get the right id for app exchange packages currently installed in my devhub:

```
$ sfdx force:package:installed:list -u [DevHubAlias]

=== Installed Package Versions [2]
ID                  PACKAGE ID          PACKAGE NAME           NAMESPACE  PACKAGE VERSION ID  VERSION NAME  VERSION
──────────────────  ──────────────────  ─────────────────────  ─────────  ──────────────────  ────────────  ────────
0A346000000qUm7CAE  03336000000DlP2AAK  HEDA                   hed        04t360000011zP6AAI  HEDA 1.43     1.43.0.3
0A346000000H6SeCAK  033C00000006mUuIAI  Apsona for Salesforce  apsona     04tC0000000ggXVIAY  Update        1.8.0.3

$ sfdx force:package:install -p 04t360000011zP6AAI -u scratch -w 5
```

Note: use the -p parameter instead of the old -i param.

Note: the HEDA package I am installing also required some additional setup in the scratch org before I could install it. Specifically I had to create a dummy account record type.

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks! ..one question I have, does this package now need to be added to the sfdx-project.json file? I seem to be unable to create a package version due to components from managed packages on lightning record pages. I can push to a scratch org ok, but only once I have installed the managed package.

Comment: ^^ I found my answer here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252540/creating-package-version-of-package-depending-on-some-other-packages

Answer (score 15):

To install a *First Generation Managed Package* via sfdx, you do it the same way you do it with the metadata API. The command looks like this:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d packages
```

The `packages` folder contains a `package.xml` file with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>InstalledPackage</name>
    </types>
    <version>40.0</version>
</Package>
```

The packages folder should contain a sub-folder named `installedPackages`. Within that folder, you should have installedPackage files that contain data like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InstalledPackage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <versionNumber>1.61</versionNumber>
    <password>package-password</password>
</InstalledPackage>
```

Password is optional unless required by the package.

The file name for the package will be `namespace.installedPackage`. For example, since your package's namespace is `ldt`, the file name would be `ldt.installedPackage`.

You can install multiple packages in a single deployment. Each package can succeed/fail independently of the others.

This will not work for *Second Generation Managed Packages*. For those, use the `sfdx force:package:install` command. You can write a shell script to automate installing many packages in a preferred order of dependencies.

Comment: @ak_1 You should have a folder (I called it packages), the file packages\package.xml (with the contents from this answer), and the file packages\installedPackages\ldt.installedPackage (that contains the second XML block). You need the version number obtained from setup in the `<version>X.XX</version>`.

Comment: thanks for immediate response clearly this links explains [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_api_introduction.htm] the same which i am able to follow more clearly with your explaination. thank you

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox this exactly worked for me thanks for your help!

Comment: @ak_1 I'm glad I was able to help you out.

Comment: @sfdcfox When creating the packages folder and sub folders for each installed package, it's mentioned that the name of the file in the sub-folder should be namespace.installedPackage, however what if a namespace has not been set for the org, what would the name of the file be at that point?

Comment: @Hect1c As far as I'm aware, it only works on managed packages. For unmanaged packages, you'd use force:package:install instead. You shouldn't ordinarily be working with unmanaged packages like this, though; that's what DX packaging is for.

Comment: @sfdcfox Can we install third party package using this based on namespace only and no id?

Comment: @TusharSharma You need either the version number or the ID. If you're using the technique in this answer, you need the version number and the password, if protected. If you're using `force:package:install`, you need the package version ID, but not the version itself. If you're not sure what version you have, you can retrieve them via [InstalledPackage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_installedpackage.htm) or `force:package:installed:list`.

Comment: @sfdcfox It seems like this approach with deployment of 'namespace.installedPackage' xml doesn't work when trying to install 2nd generation package published in app exchange. Despite using the right namespace and version number, it just throws an error that such package is not found. After installing such package manually by url and doing retrieval of installedPackage artifacts with '*' in package.xml, we've got list of all the packages but except that one. It's like it's using another type of metadata or what. But it still works fine when installing via sfdx command.

Comment: @wesaw Correct. 2GMPs can share a namespace, so the version number and namespace are insufficient to uniquely identify a package. As far as I can tell, you can only use the install URL or DX command. This answer was written before 2GMP was released, I believe, so it doesn't mention that.

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried using:

```
sfdx force:package:install -i 04t6A0000004eytQAA
```

Docs for this are found in the CLI [command reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_package.htm#cli_reference_force_package).

The only thing is that you'd need to know the ID of the package to pass to the command, but if you can get that, you should be in good shape.

**EDIT**

After doing some playing around with this now, when you run the install of an app exchange managed package through the UI, the package Id (or rather, the package version Id if I'm not mistaken) is shown in the address bar of your browser.

[image: Please do not consider this an endorsement of Skuid. I have no affiliation to them, rather it was the first package that came to mind.]

This is the value you need to supply. Taking that Id value, I have now successfully done the following:

```
$ sfdx force:project:create -n test-project
target dir = /Users/pchittum/Stuff/git/sfdx-pilot
   create test-project/sfdx-project.json
   create test-project/README.md
   create test-project/config/project-scratch-def.json

$ cd test-project/
$ sfdx force:org:create -f config/project-scratch-def.json -s 
Successfully created scratch org: 00D0v0000008eXmEAI, username: test-mffvsibtb6ly@pchittum_company.net

$ sfdx force:package:install -i 04t4A000000cESSQA2 
PackageInstallRequest is still InProgress or Unknown. You can query the status using
sfdx force:package:install:get -i 0Hf0v0000008QWdCAM 

$ sfdx force:package:install:get -i 0Hf0v0000008QWdCAM 
Successfully installed package [04t4A000000cESSQA2]
```

> Please note I have no affiliation with the above AppExchange partner. It was just the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Hi @pchittum i tried to use this command since i dont have the packageid for the apps in app exchange i am not sure, how to use this command. Do you have any idea of how to get the package id for app exchange apps. i tried to use the id in the app exchange but that didnt work

Comment: I just updated my answer with what I found.

Comment: Hi @pchittum, yeah this helps me as i tried to use the listingid in the app exchange instead we need to use the appid while installing. Thanks for your detailed explaination.

Comment: Using the that id, installs FormulaForce (Managed) package and not 'skuid' for me.   Its gonna make it even harder to not have a consistent ID @pchittum,

Comment: Tried as suggested by @havana59er, get the list from the devhub.  $ sfdx force:package:installed:list -u DevHub
=== Installed Package Versions [1]
ID                  PACKAGE ID          PACKAGE NAME  NAMESPACE  PACKAGE VERSION ID  VERSION NAME         VERSION
──────────────────  ──────────────────  ────────────  ─────────  ──────────────────  ───────────────────  ────────
0A31I000000LOtXSAW  033G00000006ShvIAE  Skuid         skuid      04t4A00000042DGQAY  Skuid Millau (11.0)  11.0.0.2
.. but fails too using the ID from the DeHub

Comment: Eventually, the right ID for skuid from the command `$ sfdx force:package:installed:list -u DevHub` was `04t4A00000042DGQAY` which is under `PACKAGE VERSION ID`