# Scratch Org Definition - Install Managed Package

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

Reading through the answer about installing managed packages in scratch orgs and found this one especially helpful:

[How to install managed package using Salesforce DX CLI?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/185840/how-to-install-managed-package-using-salesforce-dx-cli)

My question is this:

> How do you install a managed package when creating a scratch org via specifying in the scratch org definition file? Is it even possible?

The use case is when developing extension packages the scratch orgs will always have to have the base package installed and was looking to automate it a bit.

Kinda of getting lost in all the outdated info out there from the beta and such and can't seem to find anything that directly answers the question.

Comment: Have you tried force:mdapi:deploy followed by force:src:push? What was the result? Could you write a shell script?

Comment: @sfdcfox - Yea, that works but trying to get it al done when the org is created without having to do anything else. From what I read there is no setting in the definition file for InstalledPackage so it seems its always a multi-step process. Was hoping it could be defined in a JSON file so it is always installed on create based on the definition

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why they didn't do it that way, but that seems to be the case. I'd love to be proven wrong, though.

Comment: @sfdcfox - if i had to guess it would be due to speed. I bet it would dramatically slow down scratch org creation and interfere with the processes

Comment: I think speed shouldn't take priority if you dont get what you want. We should be able to define the structure of the scratch org, that we need. Like defining the required managed packages to be installed as a part of the scratch org, creation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We do not currently define package info in the scratch org config.

Use the CLI command `sfdx force:package:install ...` immediately after creating the scratch org.

Comment: As a roadmap thing, for those of us developing extension packages the base package is required for all scratch orgs to push the metadata. Knowing it will take longer, it would be nice to be able to define required package installs in the definition Json to automate things a bit. That way we don't have to keep going to lookup the package Id for the version we need to install

Comment: Totally understand. And we have plans to help address. For now, you can pre-build these scratch orgs via scripts and assign as needed. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Also, a BIG issue with package install is that it installs for admins only without any way to specify All users. This is a shortcoming of the MDAPI as well and is most likely why the CLI does not support it. However, for legacy packages it is impossible to install a package via the CLI (admin only) and have it work. Need the option to specify for "all users" when installing. I know Perm Sets are the way to go moving forward but lots of legacy packages without them that must be installed for all users or they do not work.

Comment: @WadeWegner So there's no any other way to have managed package installed when scratch org is created? i.e. CPQ is installing for 20-30 min which is way too long for us for CI. And we just need sobject from CPQ as we extend this functionality. Maybe there any other solution for that

Comment: @Mystery One thing you might consider is looking at the Scratch Org Snapshot pilot we're going to run shortly. This will let you setup CPQ in a scratch org once, snapshot it, then create scratch orgs from the snapshot. It would help with that performance.

Comment: I heard about shape orgs last year. Any news about release date?

Comment: @Mystery Scratch Org Shape pilot is already running: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_sfdx_pilot_shape.htm

But note that that's different than snapshot.

Comment: +1 this would be super useful - how it progressing? :o)