# Install managed packages using sfdx-project.json

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

So I was wondering or was hoping to get some clarity on the dependencies in a sfdx-project.json file.

I know that for my project / scratch org I can list managed package dependencies within the sfdx-project.json file using a packageId and versionNumber. But does that mean if I define all of the dependencies and create my scratch org will those managed packages automatically be installed or do I still need to manually install them using the sfdx-cli? I ask this because it's a bit tedious to have to install each managed package using the cli every time I recreate the scratch org.

Furthermore we have some packages that require an installationKey and after some digging I found that the key is not yet supported in the sfdx-project.json file in the following url: [Sfdx Dev Considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_considerations.htm#package2-considerations).

So even if it did in fact install the managed packages from the project config file, I would not be able to install any of the ones that require an installationkey, is that correct?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [How to install managed package using Salesforce DX CLI?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/185840/20721)

Comment: Yea that seems to be what I want, however when creating the packages folder and sub folders for each installed package, in the comment it's mentioned that the name of the file in the sub-folder should be namespace.installedPackage, however what if a namespace has not been set for the org, what would the name of the file be at that point?

Comment: Maybe either you can post a new question or you can comment on sfdcfox's answer, Maybe he would be kind enough to reply you back.

Comment: Yea I wanted to but I don't have enough reputation points to do so...haha, so was hoping to ask here and get a reply. Thanks.

Comment: Now you have. Go ahead.