# SFDX Remove packages dependencies from repository

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, package

An sfdx project was gave it to me from a repository, with the request of deploy it in a Development sandbox and start to test it with scratch orgs.
The command: `force:source:deploy` fails with this firsts lines in output:

```
force-app/main/default/settings/SocialCustomerService.settings-meta.xml                                                                                                                   Not available for deploy for this organization
force-app/main/default/settings/MapsAndLocation.settings-meta.xml                                                                                                                         Not available for deploy for this organization
force-app/main/default/installedPackages/wbsendit.installedPackage-meta.xml                                                                                                               Required field is missing: activateRSS
force-app/main/default/installedPackages/GetFeedback_Aut.installedPackage-meta.xml                                                                                                        Required field is missing: activateRSS
force-app/main/default/installedPackages/relateiq.installedPackage-meta.xml                                                                                                               Required field is missing: activateRSS
force-app/main/default/installedPackages/sf_chttr_apps.installedPackage-meta.xml                                                                                                          Required field is missing: activateRSS
force-app/main/default/installedPackages/SCSConnectedApp.installedPackage-meta.xml                                                                                                        Required field is missing: activateRSS
force-app/main/default/installedPackages/sf_com_apps.installedPackage-meta.xml                                                                                                            Required field is missing: activateRSS
force-app/main/default/installedPackages/Dropbox_for_SF.installedPackage-meta.xml                                                                                                         Required field is missing: activateRSS
force-app/main/default/installedPackages/SocialService.installedPackage-meta.xml                                                                                                          Required field is missing: activateRSS
```

After check on the folder `installedPackages`, I can see several packages installed

[image]

My question here is: What are my choices?

1. It is possible to remove this packages dependencies rigth from the source? How can do this?
2. This kind of project could only be deployed to a scratch org from the production Dev Hub?
3. Accordingly to my understanding, packages like social customer services are not available in dev orgs, it's is true?

Thank you very much in advance for any guidance you can provide me.

Comment: See [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/185840/2984). You can install the packages in various ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `InstalledPackage`

Your installed package metadata is out of date relative to your API version. The `activateRSS` key is required in `InstalledPackage` metadata post API version 43.0; see the [Metadata API reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_installedpackage.htm).

You can manually add this key to the XML source of the `installedPackage-meta.xml` files.

### Settings Entities

Metadata API Settings entities won't deploy to orgs that don't have access to the accompanying feature. I am not closely familiar with the licensing or edition restrictions for the two features mentioned here. You may be able to safely remove them, if your source code does not depend upon changes they introduce to the org's shape.

### General Questions

> It is possible to remove this packages dependencies rigth from the source? How can do this?

Possibly. It depends on whether the other metadata in your project includes references to any packaged components from these managed packages. Such metadata will fail to deploy if its dependency is not present, so you *can* figure it out by trial and error, but it'll take a lot of fiddling with different combinations of the managed packages to locate the absolute minimal installation.

> This kind of project could only be deployed to a scratch org from the production Dev Hub?

Deployments to a scratch org are from the source code, which is the source of truth in the SFDX development model. You can't deploy directly from one org to another with scratch orgs (they're not change set destinations).

You may or may not be able to deploy source pulled from production to a scratch org without further configuration. It depends heavily on the extent to which the source relies on specific feature configuration and other aspects of the "shape" of production. Some of those features (like Person Accounts or Multicurrency) can be created in the scratch org by altering its definition file, while others require different kinds of build automation to achieve (like OWDs on standard objects).

> Accordingly to my understanding, packages like social customer services are not available in dev orgs, it's is true?

I'm not an expert in that feature. It is not available in my developer org but I don't know much about its licensure or scratch org availability.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response David.

Answer (score 0):

If the dependencies are not required in your sources, you can use SFDX Essentials to remove the dependencies from SFDX files

https://github.com/nvuillam/sfdx-essentials#essentialschange-dependency-version

Example with FinServ package:

```
$ sfdx essentials:change-dependency-version -n FinServ -r
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Nicolas there is a lot of information

Comment: You're welcome :) if you have any question on the plugin use don't hesitate to ask :)

Comment: Hi Nicolas, how can post you a use example of the plugin? Because I don't know if I am using it correctly.
Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: I think that you can do something like :
- delete the 2 settings files in settings folder
- delete the package meta files in installedPackages
- run sfdx essentials:change-dependency-version -n wbsendit -r
- run sfdx essentials:change-dependency-version -n SocialService -r
etc ...
then sfdx force:source:push

Comment: Thanks, will try this, it just takes some time and tought i was using it wrong...

Comment: it browses,parse (and update when necessary all the files of sfdx project to check for references to remove,that's why it may take a while :)